# Suppress output of a command while recording output from "time"

Tags: bash, output, stderr

I have some command which launches in this way:

```
./mycommand -arg=word
```

I measure execution time and write output to file:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%K %e" ./mycommand -arg=word 2>file
```

However, mycommand has also `stderr` output. So `file` contains mixed data from both (`time` and `mycommand`). How can I suppress `mycommand` output and save `time` data?

Comment: There's an entry in the BashFAQ about this. That said, it's easier if you use the shell-builtin time, not /usr/bin/time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `time -f "%R" ls` gives me
`-f: command not found`

Comment: Yes, that's the reason I'm using the `TIMEFORMAT` variable, not the `-f` argument, in the branch of my answer that suggests using the shell-builtin `time` rather than the OS-provided one.

Answer (score 2):

If the nature of your process is such that a shell startup won't interfere with the timing too much, one simple approach is to have a shell run the direction as a subprocess of `time`:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%K %e" sh -c '"$0" "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1' ./mycommand -arg=word
```

I would also suggest using the bash-builtin version of `time` instead of the external one, which lets you use tricks  documented in [BashFAQ #32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032):

```
TIMEFORMAT='%R' # replace for whatever is equivalent to your "%K %e"
timing=$(time { ./mycommand >/dev/null 2>&1; } 2>&1)
```

Comment: Does `sh -c ''` changes relative path? Now `arg` can't be recognized due to relative path

Comment: It gives me an error ./mycommand: 1: ./mycommand: -arg=word: not found

Comment: No, `sh -c` does not change path (unless you have an `ENV` variable that points to a script that changes directory, that is).

Comment: ...that said, the error there was caused by `$0` consuming the command name, leaving it out of `"$@"`; see edits addressing that concern.